# How can I insert empty rows/columns in a google spreadsheet through google_drive gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-drive-api

I need to insert some empty rows in a google spreadsheet dynamically with ruby. Could google_drive gem do it for me? If not, which gem would make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to write an empty string to the cell in the highest number row you want to be empty and then save the file.

Comment: Does this sentence make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The `google_drive` gem has a method called `max_rows=`(https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/0491c4a27fc4ef7c017a442b04616569f7aac18a/lib/google_drive/worksheet.rb#L172) It can be used to add extra blank rows to the end of a worksheet.